# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError chilkat library

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries, nohup, chilkat

I am sure I can load libchilkat.jnilib file. When I change correct path to wrong path , change error can't load library. So I am sure my library load. (I use try and catch and pass correctly.) Upload this library working. After that lines when I want to use this library partials like: `CkGlobal glob = new CkGlobal();`

I got this error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init()V] with root cause com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init()V

I search but nothing found.This error similar like `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`: but different because other `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError include 'Native code library failed to load.'`

I am sure my library load.

If I run my project 'mvn exec:java' working this code. Everything is okey,
but I want to run my code using nohup on GC.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing the environment. `jnilib` is typically for macOS. What OS do you have on GC?

Comment: I use my local jnilib file. (MacOs). But I use on GC libchilkat.so file (Centos).   Both of two side (local and GC) get same error. Both of two side working correctly mvn exec:java

Comment: Do you have any idea how to work nohup with maven correctly?

Comment: It's really hard to judge what happens inside your project without looking at source code and without your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
import com.chilkatsoft.CkGlobal;

public class Simple {

  String PATH_TO_LIB="/full/path/to/lib";

  static {
    System.load(PATH_TO_LIB + "/libchilkat.so");
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    CkGlobal glob = new CkGlobal();
  }
}
```

and compilation like this:

```
> javac -cp ./chilkat.jar Simple.java
> java -cp .:./chilkat.jar Simple
> nohup java -cp .:chilkat.jar Simple
```

it works as expected. I suggest to take a look at the exact command executed by Maven - by putting `-X` before your goal.

Comment: thanks. I tried  'nohup mvn exec:java&' and worked. But actually give me error lines. but my code and project working correctly. I do not understand :)  2 or 3 days later I have to upload my project new version on GC. If my project not working correctly I will try this. Thanks again.